# Echo Javascript result in php for condition

Tags: javascript, php

Can anyone help me about this to simply cut the chase of in my code below i want to echo the value of result in php so that i can use it in conditional statement can anyone help me?

I have it working but  i want also to echo the txtResult Value into php

```
PS: IT IS EXECUTED ON THE SAME PAGE AND WITHOUT SUBMIT BUTTON T_T
<form method="post">
        <h2>Add two textbox values without pressing anybuttons</h2>
        <label>First</label>
        <select type="text" id="txtFirstNo" placeholder="First Number" onkeyup="sum()" />
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
    </select><br><br>
        <label>Second</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtSecondNo" placeholder="Second Number" onkeyup="sum()" />
        <br />
        <div style="padding-top:10px">
            Result:
            <input type="text" id="txtResult" name="dan" value="" />
        </div>
</form>

<?php
//echo it here!!!
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function sum() {
            var txtFirstNo = document.getElementById('txtFirstNo').value;
            var txtSecondNo = document.getElementById('txtSecondNo').value;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNo) * parseInt(txtSecondNo);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('txtResult').value = result;     
            }

        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Php is server side scripting language.
And js is client side language so from my point of view it cannot communicate without any trigger.
 Like to

1. Submit data or form with JQ and get data in php.
2. Instead of php use Labels to print using JS.
3. Write some function like onFocusOut or onKeyUp to send data.

Comment: can you give me a hint or tip on it? or sample if possible?